# Two kinds of bindings on one TextBox?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, wpf-controls

Currently I've got the following binding:

```
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Mode=TwoWay, Path=SearchText, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}">
```

In the code when the search text changes I'm performing an expensive, long-running operation so the trigger is set to `LostFocus` in order to only perform that after the user hits enter or tab.

I'd like to additionally enable another control as soon as the text in that text box is non empty, though.

Can I have a second binding in the `TextBox` or bind the other control to the current content of my text box in the XAML directly..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all **default value for `UpdateSourceTrigger` of Text DP is `LostFocus`,** you don't have to do that manually. Also, default Mode is TwoWay for Text DP, you can omit that as well.

Second, `UpdateSourceTrigger` signifies that source value of binding should update on which operation. So, definitely you can enable/disable another control and for that you need to have binding on another control.

This will work because binding of DP (i.e. IsEnabled) for another control gets updated when source property i.e. Text DP gets changed.

```
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBox x:Name="txt" Text="{Binding SearchText}"/>
        <Button Content="TestButton"
                IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=txt, Path=Text,
                            Converter={StaticResource StringToBoolConverter}}"/>
    </StackPanel>
```

Comment: Sweet! If I have also bound a command to that button will the `IsEnabled` binding take preference over the command's enablement settings?

Comment: No, in that case `CommandManager` will override the value of `IsEnabled`. Ideally enable/disable code should be at one place. Moreover, it depends on which gets invoked last. If `IsEnabled` binding gets evaluated last it will override the commandManager CanExecute value and vice versa. So, the last one will always win and override the value.

Comment: You can continue use Commands although. In case don't want CanExecute to affect your button, don't supply Predicate for CanExecute and default implementation of ICommand and should return true always. Rest is your call if you want to go with Click too.

Answer (score 1):

You can bind the other control to `Text` property of the `TextBox`. With that the other control will be immediately affected when `Text` property changed, even before LostFocus event raised :

```
<TextBox x:Name="txtSearch" Text="{Binding Mode=TwoWay, Path=SearchText, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}">
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Text, ElementName=txtSearch}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi without using binding too much myself, i reasonly did a small multibinding experiment just to get to know the binding concept a bit bitter.

This should clarify a bit how binding can work for your advantages:

```
  <StackPanel>
    <Slider Name="SliderFontSize" Margin="3" Minimum="1" Maximum="40" Value="10" TickFrequency="1" TickPlacement="TopLeft" IsSnapToTickEnabled="True" />
    <TextBox Name="TextBoxTextContent" Margin="5" Text="Denne tekst er en test" />
    <ListBox Name="ListBoxColors" BorderBrush="Black" Margin="5" >
        <ListBoxItem Tag="Red" Content="Red" ></ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem Tag="Yellow" Content="Yellow" ></ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem Tag="Green" Content="Green" ></ListBoxItem>
    </ListBox>
    <TextBlock Margin="3" Name="TextBlockSampleText" Height="50" FontSize="{Binding ElementName=SliderFontSize, Path=Value, Mode=TwoWay}"  
               Text="{Binding ElementName=TextBoxTextContent, Path=Text}" Foreground="{Binding ElementName=ListBoxColors, Path=SelectedItem.Tag}" />
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBlock Name="TextBlockExactSize" Text="Exact Size:" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
        <!-- I .Net 4.5 er der mulighed for at smide en delay property på som starter hvergang der er foretaget en ændring, men updater først
             sourcen når delay tiden er nået. og resetter hver gang der foretages en ny ændring. Delay=500 (halvt sekundt) -->
        <TextBox Name="TextBoxExactSize" Text="{Binding ElementName=TextBlockSampleText, Path=FontSize, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit}" 
                 HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="100" Margin="10 5" TextChanged="TextBoxExactSize_TextChanged" />
    </StackPanel>
    <Button Name="ButtonClose" IsCancel="True" Content="Close" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="30" Width="100" Margin="5" Click="ButtonClose_Click" />
</StackPanel>
```

In code behind:

```
private void TextBoxExactSize_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
  pm_RetrievedBindingExpression = TextBoxExactSize.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty);
  pm_RetrievedBindingExpression.UpdateSource();
}
```

//This method is nessesary if the UpdateSourceTrigger is set to 'Explicit'. This way you can do some code behind in your event, and update the source whenever the method has done its job. If you don't like this behavior, you can changed Explicit to PropertyChanged, which updates your property as soon as a change occurs.

Just create a new window c/p it in, and play around with it. Hope this helps :)